# How does it happen there are different comment characters in Linux configuration files?

Tags: linux

I'm familiar with `#` comment character in Linux configuration files. There are a few other examples--

[Kernel modules under /etc/modules-load.d/](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Automatic_module_handling): *"Empty lines and lines whose first non-whitespace character is # or ; are ignored."*

[X's Xresources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources#Commenting): *"To add a comment to your Xresources file, simply prefix it with an exclamation mark (!)..."*

***How does it happen there are different comment characters in Linux configuration files?***

Is it a Frankenstein thing? It's so simple and different examples are a surprise whenever I find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A configuration file is read by a program by implementing a [Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser) and [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) (a lexical analyzer) of some kind. That parser contains the code that gives meaning to the characters in the document for that specific program.

A program can implement whatever kind of parser they want, and thus the syntax of the config file has to conform to its expectations. if it was written to recognize `#` or `//` or `REM`, or whether it treats all text in [] as setting names, and all lines that start with anything but an [ are treated as comment text, is entirely up to the person writing or implementing the parser.

The parser built into the kernel follows one set of rules, and the parser built into X uses a different set. We can't read minds so its unlikely you will ever learn why that choice was made. All that matters is that it was, and you need to use those rules when editing the config files for whatever system.

Comment: _"We can't read minds so its unlikely you will ever learn why that choice was made."_ That's why we have SO, and we can ask. ahaha.

Comment: @xtian SO is *not* SU ;)